# mysql : group results from requests

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql request gives me:

```
        SELECT 
        sf_guard_user.id, sf_guard_user.username, sf_guard_user.avatar_time, fromid, toid,sum(chatMessage.fromidlu) - sum(chatMessage.toidlu) as nonlus
        FROM chatMessage, sf_guard_user
        WHERE (chatMessage.fromid = sf_guard_user.id AND toid=16595 AND toidhidden=0) OR (chatMessage.toid = sf_guard_user.id AND fromid=16595 AND fromidhidden=0)
        GROUP by fromid
```

[image]

I want to apply another SQL to this result so final result is makes the sum on 'nonlus'

```
SELECT id, username, avatar_time, fromid, toid, sum(nonlus) FROM 
**this request**
order by id
```

I tried

```
SELECT id, username, avatar_time, fromid, toid, sum(nonlus) FROM (
          SELECT 
            sf_guard_user.id, sf_guard_user.username, sf_guard_user.avatar_time, fromid, toid,sum(chatMessage.fromidlu) - sum(chatMessage.toidlu) as nonlus
            FROM chatMessage, sf_guard_user
            WHERE (chatMessage.fromid = sf_guard_user.id AND toid=16595 AND toidhidden=0) OR (chatMessage.toid = sf_guard_user.id AND fromid=16595 AND fromidhidden=0)
            GROUP by fromid)
Group by id
```

But get error

> Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Literally just type the letter `a` after your `)` after your first `GROUP BY`.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about this. Did you try simply putting the error message into SO's search box?

Comment: You should learn to use explicit `JOIN` instead of cross products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to assign an alias to inner `select`, try the following:

```
SELECT id, username, avatar_time, fromid, toid, sum(nonlus) FROM (
          SELECT 
            sf_guard_user.id as id, sf_guard_user.username as username, sf_guard_user.avatar_time as avatar_time, fromid, toid, sum(chatMessage.fromidlu) - sum(chatMessage.toidlu) as nonlus
            FROM chatMessage, sf_guard_user
            WHERE (chatMessage.fromid = sf_guard_user.id AND toid=16595 AND toidhidden=0) OR (chatMessage.toid = sf_guard_user.id AND fromid=16595 AND fromidhidden=0)
            GROUP by fromid) a
Group by a.id
```

Comment: when you group by id, any columns if not a group by column in the select  need to have aggregation.

Comment: @PeterHe MySQL is permissive about this. And it's not required for columns that are uniquely defined by the grouped columns.

Comment: It depends on sql_mode, and can get unexpected results. Standard sql does not allow this.